# Optimize AWK script for large dataset

Tags: bash, awk

For the following input data,

```
Chr C   rsid    D   A1  A2  ID1_AA  ID1_AB  ID1_BB  ID2_AA  ID2_AB  ID2_BB  ID3_AA  ID3_AB  ID3_BB  ID4_AA  ID4_AB  ID4_BB  ID5_AA  ID5_AB  ID5_BB
10  p   rsid1   q   A   G   0.00    0.85    0.15    0.70    0.10    0.20    0.40    0.50    0.10    0.30    0.30    0.40    0.10    0.20    0.80
10  p   rsid2   q   C   T   0.90    0.10    0.00    0.80    0.10    0.10    0.70    0.10    0.20    0.30    0.40    0.30    0.30    0.20    0.40
10  p   rsid3   q   A   G   0.40    0.50    0.10    0.80    0.20    0.00    0.20    0.30    0.50    0.50    0.30    0.20    0.20    0.30    0.40
```

I need to generate the following output data.

```
rsid        ID1         ID2         ID3         ID4         ID5
rsid1      2.15        1.50        1.70        2.10        2.90
rsid2      1.10        1.30        1.50        2.00        1.90
rsid3      1.70        1.20        2.30        1.70        2.00
```

The table show the sum of 3 columns `(_AA, _AB & _BB)` by multiplying with a constant factor `(1, 2, 3)` for every ID `(ID1, ID2, ID3, etc)`.

```
Example: for rsID1 --> ID1 -> (ID1_AA*1 + ID1_AB*2 + ID1_BB*3) = (0.00*1 + 0.85*2 + 0.15*3) = 2.15
```

I wrote the following AWK script to establish the task and it works absolutely fine.

**Please note: I'm a very beginner in AWK.**

```
awk '{
    if(NR <= 1) { # header line
        str = $3; 
        for(i=7; i<=NF; i+=3) {
            split($i,s,"_”);
            str = str"\t"s[1]
        }
        print str
    }  else { # data line
        k = 0; 
        for(i=7; i<=NF; i+=3) 
            arr[k++] = $i*1 + $(i+1)*2 + $(i+2)*3; 
        str=$3; 
        for(i=0; i<=(NF-6)/3; i++) 
            str = str"\t"arr[i]; 
        print str
    }
}'  input.txt > out.txt
```

Later I was told the input data can be as big as 60 Million rows & 300 Thousand columns which means the output data will be 60Mx100K. If I'm not wrong, AWK reads one line at a time & hence at an instant there will be 300K columns of data held in memory. Is it a problem? Given the situation, how can I improve my code?

Comment: There are some minor changes that could be made but it's not certain that they would have a significant effect on the performance. Other tweaks, such as factoring out the common code from each branch and using the idiomatic `condition { action }` rather than `if`/`else`, are more related to style than anything else. I guess that if your script works, this falls more into the scope of [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks for your comments @TomFenech, I'll update my script. Just a quick questions, one of my colleague pointed me to rewrite the script in `bash` using `call by reference`. I really don't see a point doing that. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how the concept of _call by reference_ applies to this situation but processing text files, especially large ones, in bash is almost certainly *not* the way to go.

Comment: I thought the same. A couple of questions  
1. Do u think making use of a low level language like C and adopting *call by reference* will fix the problem of loading data into memory?
2. In your opinion if I take your `condition { action }` into consideration, will that be the best code to solve the above problem?

Comment: @DhiwaTdG there is no problem with handling 300,000 columns of data per line at a time. That is nothing. Writing the code in C would do nothing but make your code more fragile, lengthier, and probably slower. Writing it in bash would be wildly inappropriate and you should only do that if you have 2 weeks vacation coming up while you can leave it running. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While both approaches have pros/cons and they can both handle any number of rows/columns since they only store 1 row at a time in memory, I'd use this approach rather than [the answer posted by Akshay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41835714/1745001) since you have 300,000 columns per line so his approach would require you to test `NR==1` almost 100,000 times per line whereas the approach below will just perform the test 1 time per line so it should be noticeably more efficient:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
{
    printf "%s", $3
    if (NR==1) {
        gsub(/_[^[:space:]]+/,"")
        for (i=7; i<=NF; i+=3) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, $i
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i=7; i<=NF; i+=3) {
            printf "%s%.2f", OFS, $i + $(i+1)*2 + $(i+2)*3
        }
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
rsid    ID1     ID2     ID3     ID4     ID5
rsid1   2.15    1.50    1.70    2.10    2.90
rsid2   1.10    1.30    1.50    2.00    1.90
rsid3   1.70    1.20    2.30    1.70    2.00
```

I highly recommend you read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn what awk is and how to use it.

Comment: The code looks very efficient. Is this similar to @Tom Fenech's suggestion of making use of `condition {action}` logic?

Comment: No. I was going to use that but then decided not to so I could reuse the common code surrounding the loops for both cases.

Comment: `^1` got something new to learn today, small but effective one

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
            {
              printf("%s",$3);
              for(i=7;i<=NF; i+=3)
              {
                if(FNR==1)
                {
                   sub(/_.*/,"",$i)
                   f = $i
                }else
                {
                    f = sprintf("%5.2f",$i*1 + $(i+1)*2 + $(i+2)*3)
                }
                   printf("%s%s",OFS,f)
              }
                print ""
            }
    ' file
```

**Output**

```
rsid     ID1     ID2     ID3     ID4     ID5
rsid1    2.15    1.50    1.70    2.10    2.90
rsid2    1.10    1.30    1.50    2.00    1.90
rsid3    1.70    1.20    2.30    1.70    2.00
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do u think making use of a low level language like C?

C++ or C is not automagically faster than awk, also, the code is less readable and more fragile.

I show another solution using `c++`, to compare

```
//p.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

//to modify this value
#define COLUMNS 5

int main() {
    char column3[256];
    bool header=true;
    while (scanf("%*s\t%*s\t%255s\t%*s\t%*s\t%*s\t", column3) == 1) {
        printf("%s", column3);
        if(header){
            header=false;
            char name[256];
            for(int i=0; i<COLUMNS; ++i){
                scanf("%[^_]_%*s\t%*s\t%*s\t", name);
                printf("\t%s", name);
            }
        }else{
            float nums[3];
            for(int i=0; i<COLUMNS; ++i){
                scanf("%f %f %f", nums, nums + 1, nums + 2);
                float sum = nums[0]+nums[1]*2+nums[2]*3;
                printf("\t%2.2f", sum);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Run it, like

```
g++ p.cpp -o p
cat file | ./p
```

**Benchmark**

with 1 millon of lines in input and 300 columns

- Ed Morton solution: 2m 34s
- c++: 1m 19s